# highchart-export-server --batch command running but not converting json into png

Tags: java, cmd, highcharts

I have installed highcharts export server using command - **npm install highcharts-export-server -g** (v2.1.0)
and I have node of latest version - v14.17.3.

Now I have created a JSON file and to convert this into png file I am running the command -

```
highcharts-export-server -batch "C:\apps\sdplatform\reports\blitz-qa3\pod-5e4d8ede0c832d6279ff7dc6_61162655777300.json=C:\apps\sdplatform\reports\blitz-qa3\pod-5e4d8ede0c832d6279ff7dc6_61162655777300.png"
```

at location C:\apps\sdplatform\reports\blitz-qa3 json file 5e4d8ede0c832d6279ff7dc6_61162655777300.json is-

```
{"chart":{"type":"column","options3d":{"alpha":15,"beta":25,"depth":60,"enabled":true},"inverted":false,"polar":false,"styledMode":false},"title":{"text":"Chart Title 2","align":"left"},"credits":{"enabled":false,"text":""},"xAxis":[{"categories":["Adoption","Growth","Renewal","Inactive"],"labels":{"step":0}}],"yAxis":[{"title":{"text":"Count","align":"left"},"allowDecimals":false,"startOnTick":false,"endOnTick":true,"reversed":false}],"plotOptions":{"series":{"stacking":"","point":{"events":{"click":function(e){if(typeof this.url != 'undefined') { window.location = this.url;}}}},"dataLabels":{"enabled":true,"color":"","formatter":function () {return ' '+this.y+'<br>';},"softConnector":false,"allowOverlap":false},"cursor":"pointer"}},"series":[{"name":"MRR","type":"column","data":[{"y":376500.0,"url":"/entityobjects?filter_as_pod=5e4d8ede0c832d6279ff7dc6&filter_stage=adoption__c&entity=Customer&filter_as_pod_series_0=5e4d8ede0c832d6279ff7dc6&filter_mrr__gt=0","info":"Adoption"},{"y":29500.0,"url":"/entityobjects?filter_as_pod=5e4d8ede0c832d6279ff7dc6&filter_stage=Growth&entity=Customer&filter_as_pod_series_0=5e4d8ede0c832d6279ff7dc6&filter_mrr__gt=0","info":"Growth"},{"y":318616.0,"url":"/entityobjects?filter_as_pod=5e4d8ede0c832d6279ff7dc6&filter_stage=Renewal&entity=Customer&filter_as_pod_series_0=5e4d8ede0c832d6279ff7dc6&filter_mrr__gt=0","info":"Renewal"},{"y":127000.0,"url":"/entityobjects?filter_as_pod=5e4d8ede0c832d6279ff7dc6&filter_stage=inactive__c&entity=Customer&filter_as_pod_series_0=5e4d8ede0c832d6279ff7dc6&filter_mrr__gt=0","info":"Inactive"}]}],"exporting":{"enabled":false}}
```

after running the above --batch command in cmd I am expecting the chart image pod-5e4d8ede0c832d6279ff7dc6_61162655777300.png will get generated at C:\apps\sdplatform\reports\blitz-qa3 location but In actual nothing is happening no any .png file generated there.

[image] [image]

how can I get the chart png here?

Answer (score 0):

Once the server is properly installed and started, you can try these basic commands:
https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server#command-line-arguments

```
highcharts-export-server --infile <file_name>.json --outfile <file_name>.<file_type> --type <file_type>
highcharts-export-server --infile ./_examples/basic.json --outfile ./_examples/basic.png --type png
```

Comment: I am getting error on cmd when I am trying command - `highcharts-export-server --infile ./_examples/basic.json --outfile ./_examples/basic.png --type png`                                          Fri Jul 16 2021 15:52:02 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) [error] phantom worker 1 unexpected data - ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Intl  undefined:108
  :83 in P
  :108
  :83... where ever png is generating but showing Export server Not configured please complete the configuration by running node build.js in the export-server-root If you installed by running ... @madepiet

Comment: I guess this could be related to this issue (moment.js): https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=46550#p168332

Comment: I tried this but still facing same issue, is there any need of installing phantomjs to run highcharts-export-server?

Comment: There should be no such need - it should work by following the installation instructions here: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server#install